# Printer, email and PDF - can I use this module to print Views?

Tags: 7, views, files

I have installed [Printer, email and PDF](https://drupal.org/project/print) and I am happy with the way it renders nodes.  I was wondering if there was a way for it to print views too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be the same idea, but instead of using nid in the URL use Views page path.

**Examples:**

- print view page: `http://www.example.com/print/view-path`
- pdf view page: `http://www.example.com/printpdf/view-path`
- email view page: `http://www.example.com/printmail/view-path`